# Display total timing in Html5 audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/demos/test3.html

I am used audio "preload="none" from above website. I want to display the "total time" like other "auto play and loop". If i use the other options like "loop" the time will be displayed. But I want to display this option in "preload="none". Is it possible?? Any one help me?

**This is my Html Code:**

```
<audio src="/mp3/juicy.mp3" preload="none" />
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
  audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To suit your needs try out the `loadedmetadata` listener.

```
var displayTime = function(){
  // use audio.currentTime and audio.duration to get your time
}
var audio = // get reference to audio element
audio.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', displayTimes, false);
audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', displayTimes, false);
```

*Need more help? let me know*

Comment: this is internal script?? Sorry. I couldn't understand.

Comment: @Akash just add in in your script tag and do the necessary